# How to handle row background in Android BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, baseadapter

I am changing row background color if the fetching data from database size is more than zero as gray otherwise not changing anything.For first item i am setting default folder and remaining as list names for these lists also setting background same like above.When I scroll the list all the bacground positions are changed..I know that positions are changing while scrolling.How to solve this one?

First position should be always Default List. I am giving code snippet for understanding purpose

```
 if(position == 0)
        {
            holder.listName.setText("Default List");
            int c = //getting database table size
            if(c == 0 )
            {
                holder.rowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            list =//getting lists from database(different table)
            if(list!=null)
            {
                holder.listName.setText(list.getListName());

            }
            if(list size==0)
            {
                holder.rowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make your question more clearer.it is really difficult to understand what you exactly want. Like,what you mean by- "if the fetching data from database size is more than zero as gray otherwise not changing anything".if your database size is zero,how would you get data to be put in your list? and "For first item i am setting default folder and remaining as list names for these lists also setting background same like above." what does this mean??

Comment: Means Default list is always in zeroth position and if the elements are not available in any list item(include Default list) ,i am changing the background color to gray.i am retrieving date from database by using ArrayList<object> with setter/getter methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListItem recycled when you scroll the List that is why you are getting random background for ListItem. You  have to change background of ListItem to it default color.

as follows..

```
if(list size==0)            
     holder.rowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);       
else
     holder.rowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Thanks Sujit.Given solution working fine.I forgot the else block.